# Unable to type anything in textbox after state empty Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs/nextjs,Right now i am integrating newsletter(submit form) but once i submit form then unable to type anything in textbox,How can i fix this ? I tried with make "state" empty but still unable to type anything, Here is my current code

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        name: e.target.name.value,
        country: e.target.country.value,
        msgs: e.target.msgs.value,
      };

      axios
        .post("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",data)
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data.msg == "exist") {
            $("#msg4").show("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut();
           
            setState({
                ...state,
                name: ""
              });
          } else {
         }
        });
        return (
            <>
                    <form className="row" id="home_contact_form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    id="name"
                    placeholder="Enter Your Email"
                    value={state.name}
                    // onChange={handleChange}
                    className="input-group"
                  />
                   <input type="submit" value="send" className="sendbtn" id="sendbtn" />
                    </form> 
            </>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to couse the input be a controlled component you can do
so:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ name: '' });
```

and provide an event handler for onChange

```
const handleChange = (event) => setState({...state, name: event.target.value })

<input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    id="name"
    placeholder="Enter Your Email"
    value={state.name}
    onChange={handleChange}
    className="input-group"
 />
```